# Cannot find local host via browser - can ping localhost and 127.0.0.1 ok

Tags: windows-7, ping, localhost, wamp

I have installed wampserver to start up some PHP-scripting, but cannot call localhost
nor 127.0.0.1 via Chrome, Firefox or IE8.

I have made sure that my host-file says 127.0.0.1 localhost
I have run gpupdate /force and ipconfig /flushdns and reboot - but still no success.

The solutions above - I have gotten from other forums - but still
when I type http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 in the browsers I get nowhere.

I get fine answers from both localhost and 127.0.0.1 when I ping them.

Comment: What port did you start your webserver on - and what is the error message you get in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

Did you start the service for Apache and PHP at least?
Image below shows where to start all services.

[image]

http://www.installationwiki.org/WAMP